# To move Mac App to a second screen when it launches at the main screen/space initially?

Tags: macos, display, applescript, remote-desktop

I hope to use a apple script to move the Microsoft Remote Desktop App (MacOS version) to a second screen, center it(, and click a remote config) when it's been lunched and shown in the main screen automaticly.

I tried use the Mac Automation tool to record apple script but failed, could this question be solved by scripting?

[image]

Comment: Could you edit this to show your script and define what a “vice” screen is? Help us help you by clarifying with an edit to the body. That will trigger an anutomatic review of the temporary hold.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it be a second dispaly connected to a MacBookPro.